# How many times internal flash memory be written and erased with user data

Tags: memory, stm32, flash-memory

On my stm32 mcu there is no eeprom. So, I am using internal flash to save one byte user data to retain it between power cycles.I am doing it the following way,

1. Add Data section in memory in linker script

   MEMORY
   {
   RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 8K
   FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 64K
   DATA     (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x8003800,   LENGTH = 2K //Allocated one full flash page
   }
2. Create user data section

   .user_data :
   {
   . = ALIGN(4);
   *(.user_data)
   . = ALIGN(4);
   } >DATA
3. Create a variable to store in flash

   **attribute**((**section**(".user_data"))) const uint8_t userConfig[64]
4. Write data using following functions,

   HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

   __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR );

   FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_11, VOLTAGE_RANGE_3);

   HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, &userConfig[index], someData);

   HAL_FLASH_Lock();

My question is how many writes can be done this way to the internal flash to save the user data?

Comment: The data sheet for the specific part you are using ought to say how many write cycles the flash is rated for.  It won't necessarily be the same for all stm32 devices.

Comment: @NateEldredge I thought so too. But I do not seem to find that info in the datasheet and reference manual
Datasheet - https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g031k4.pdf
Reference manual - https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00371828-stm32g0x1-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: I found a application note for eeprom emulation which has a flash endurance table for various stm32 MCUs at page 17- https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00311483-eeprom-emulation-techniques-and-software-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Check out the "Flash memory endurance and data retention" table in the device datasheet (not the Ref manuals). I can find te information for every controller I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics of a STM32 internal Flash memory are always detailed in the product datasheet. For example on a STM32H743 the endurance is 10kcycles.

You can deduce from this that internal flash is not adapted to your use case (unless power cycles are exceptional events).

if you absolutely need to write the internal Flash many times (which I strongly doubt) you may want to have a look to Flash Translation Layer concept. It is a software layer that provides a kind of virtual to physical memory mapping and allows to reduce the Flash wear.

Comment: If I use the Power Voltage Detector feature of the mcu and only wirte the flash when power is removed and read when power is applied. That should also reduce the wear right?

Comment: I don't know. How often a power off can happen ? If it is an exceptional event it might be sufficient.